# Existence of a limit related to integrals - prove or disprove

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $f,g$ be continuous functions in the interval $[0,1]$.

Let $$F(x) = \int_{0}^xf(t) \,dt$$

Let $$G(x) = \int_{0}^xg(t) \,dt$$

then the $\lim_{x\to 0} {F(x) \over G(x)} $ is not defined

I'm trying to disprove the statement. I'm looking for a function that its integral when x tends to $0$ isn't $0$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x g(t)\,dt=0$$

Now, use L'Hospital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  You will need additional conditions for $g$.

Comment: trying. Thanks for the hint. just to make sure the statement is correct?

Comment: If $g(0)\ne 0$, then all should be good and the result is $f(0)/g(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(t) = g(t) = 1$.

Then $F(x) = G(x) = x$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} = 1$$

Comment: wait. hmm, what happens when x --> 0. are you sure that F(x) = x? and not 0? because integral from a point to the same point is zero

Comment: More generally, the limit is $f(0)/g(0)$ for $g(0)\ne 0$.

Comment: @user21312 $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.  What is $F(x)$ when $f(t)=1$?

Comment: I think I got it now. it's x

Comment: We take $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$, not $\frac{\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)}{\lim_{x \to 0}G(x)}$.